# Collection was modified exception on datatable.Copy()

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I am getting the following exception when I call `datatable.Copy()` and I'm not sure why. I applied a lock to avoid this issue but it didn't seem to fix it. The exception doesn't happen consistently so I know it has to do with threading. Am I misunderstanding how locks work?

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.
>     at System.Data.RBTree`1.RBTreeEnumerator.MoveNext()
>     at System.Data.DataTable.Copy()

Code:

```
DataTable dt;

lock (ClassName.datatable)
{
    dt = ClassName.datatable.Copy();
}
```

`ClassName` is a type and not an object (there was some confusion in a previous question of mine).

Comment: Are you using the same lock *everywhere* use modify or read the table?

Comment: No I don't think I do.  Does lock() only lock against other lock() blocks?  If so that's likely my mistake.

Comment: Yes, it does. (Well, or calls to `Monitor.Enter` for the same monitor.) It's worth being *very* clear about what `lock` does before moving on. Do you want me to add this (with a bit more detail) as an answer?

Comment: Yes please.  I want to make sure I know what to fix before I spend time fixing it.  It's also worth learning about this because I don't see threading going away any time soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by comments, you've misunderstood how `lock` works. It's a *cooperative* scheme, whereby two threads can't hold the lock on the same monitor at a time. Unless a thread tries to "enter" the lock, either using a `lock` statement or [`Monitor.Enter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.enter.aspx) (and related calls), the fact that another thread *holds* the lock is irrelevant.

It's a bit like having a bathroom with no lock but an "engaged" or "vacant" sign... no-one is *forced* to either change the sign themselves or take any notice of its current state... but if everyone *agrees* to do both, you avoid embarrassing situations.

Personally I try to avoid locking on a monitor which is visible to any other code, so I'd probably have:

```
private readonly object tableLock = new objet();
private readonly DataTable table;

...

lock (tableLock)
{
    ...
}
```

You need to at least potentially obtain the lock *everywhere* you use the table - and of course if you pass it to other methods which might store a reference to it, or you're given it by some other code, you really have very little control over what happens to it.